# Should i use tabHost in a tabHost for this setup?

Tags: java, android-layout, android-tabhost

I am doing a school project to make an information app on android studio. I am required to create a tabHost of 4 tabs. In 1 of the tab, i have to be able to swipe left and right to display 5 different activity. Is it correct to put another tabHost in the 2nd tab activity?

Is there another more efficient way to do this?

[image: I am supposed to display like this.]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

By setting, the TableLayout and ViewPager linkage.

```
yourTableLayout.setupWithViewPager(yourViewPager)
```

Override getPageTitle(int position) in ViewPager's Adapter

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return yourTabTitle.get(position)
}
```

Comment: this answer is correct, the `ViewPager` + `TabLayout` possible use like a pucture un question